# How many ways can one draw a 5 card hand from a standard deck of cards and have at least 1 of every suit?

Tags: combinatorics

There are:

$4*{13 \choose 2}$ ways to select the first 2 cards. 
 ${13 \choose 1}$ ways to select the remaining 3 cards.

so we have 
$$4*{13\choose 2}*{13 \choose 1}^3$$ ways, or do we have $$\frac{4*{13\choose 2}*{13 \choose 1}^3}{5!}$$

since ordering does not matter.
 I am having trouble going about this problem so that I don't consider the order of selection.

The answer to a similar problem:

In how many ways can we generate pairings from 20 players for the first round of a tennis tournament.

We get:

$$\frac{{20 \choose 2}...{2 \choose 2}}{10!} = \frac{20!}{(10!)*(2^{10})}$$

Here we divide by 10! since the method generates each ordering of pairs separately, which we do not care about.

Why doesn't the same apply to the problem above?

Comment: Your first count is correct.  Notice that you chose the suit from which two cards are drawn, two cards of that suit, and one card from each of the other suits.  You did not specify the order in which the cards are drawn.

Answer (score 1):

In the first question, there are are four ways to select the suit with two cards.  Say that happens to be spades.  Then there are $13$ ways to select a Heart, $13$ ways to select a Diamond, and $13$ ways to select a Club.  All the suits are different, so there is no double counting.

In the tournament, there is no such distinction between the pairs.  Arranging them in a different sequence changes nothing, and we do have to adjust for double counting.

Comment: Yes but I am asking that, we could have selected the double suit 2 cards apart from each other, and that would result in the same hand, they don't have to both be chosen together. But this method without dividing by 5! seems to double count based on the order that we drew each of the 5 cards.

Comment: Not so.  There is no way you could have chosen the two cards of the same suit two apart with this method of counting.  The need to adjust for double-counting is an artifact of the method you use to count.  I'm not saying there is no possible way of doing this problem so that double counting becomes necessary, but in the way you chose to do it originally, no double counting occurs.